# Centering a line between to nodes using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-calc

I'm trying to create a tikz picture where I have an image with some text to the right of it. Between the image and the text I want to draw a vertical line that is the same distance away from the edge of the image as from the edge of the text. See the included picture.

[image: 1]

Currently I have the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    
\node[anchor = west ,xshift=0cm, yshift=0, text width = 0.5\textwidth, right = of image]{\Huge Text};

\draw[line width=1mm](2.25,-1) -- +(0,2); 

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Important to note is that I would prefer an exact solution, not an estimation like I did by having the line at x=2.25 within the tikz picture (which 'looks' right). I would like a solution that dynamically changes location when the images is moved (the text already moves dynamically with the picture using `right=of image`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `calc` library:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[inner sep=0pt] (image) at (0,0)
    {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
    
\node[anchor=west,right=of image,inner sep=0pt] (text) {\Huge Text};

\draw[line width=1mm] ($(image.east)!0.5!(text.west)$) +(0,-1) -- +(0,1);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely, works like a charm! I tried to use the calc package, bit did not now you could use .west and .east to get the edges of nodes, thank you!